# How to use DialogFragment the right way?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'd like to use a fragment inside a dialog as well as inside an activity. Therefore the fragment was derived from `DialogFragment`.
Now the problem is, as soon as the fragment overwrites both `onCreateView()` and `onCreateDialog()` methods, displaying the fragment as a dialog crashes with `android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content`.

If `onCreateView()` gets removed, displaying as a dialog works well, but embedding the fragment in an activity, crashes with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.blah.SomeFragment did not create a view.`

Removing `onCreateDialog()` would be a solution, but where should the dialogs buttons then be wired up?

Now I'm completely puzzled how to use the same `DialogFragment` derived class in both scenarios - inside a dialog and inside an activity - isn't that what `DialogFragment` is all about? I kinda don't get it... What's the right way to use `DialogFragment`?

Comment: Did you actually look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)? It has a very detailed description. Also [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)... You can delete the question now.

Comment: You don‘t need a onCreateDialog().You just need onCreateView().

Comment: Removing onCreateDialog() might be the solution, but how do you set up the dialog buttons then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your DialogFragment to work both as a DialogFragment and a normal fragment inside other activities, you can can use `setShowsDialog` to specify which you are using, like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
   super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
   setShowsDialog( false );
}
```

and then override `onCreateDialog` and `onCreateView` like this:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder( getActivity() );
   // custom view inside the dialog
   builder.setView( createView( getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), null, savedInstanceState ) );
   return builder.create();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
   if ( getShowsDialog() ) {
      return super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
   } else {
      // custom view creation
      return createView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );
   }
}
```

In my code, I have one `BaseClassFragment` that setsShowDialog false, and then I have a subclass, `DialogBaseClassFragment`, that setsShowDialog to true and use them as appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this! The call to super.onCreateView() in case it's displayed as a dialog solved the "android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content" issue and now it's working as intended.